# How do I troubleshoot a 404 error when trying to use the GitLab API to download a raw file?

Tags: curl, terraform, gitlab-api

I am attempting to use Terraform to download a raw file from a private repo. However I am getting a 404 error.

Logs:

```
null_resource.manifest: Destroying... [id=8131279658604839368]
null_resource.manifest: Destruction complete after 0s
null_resource.manifest: Creating...
null_resource.manifest: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
null_resource.manifest (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "curl --location --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: REDACTED' -O './.terraform/REDACTED/src/manifest.yml' https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/REDACTED/repository/files/src%2Fmanifest.yml/raw?ref=REDACTED"]
null_resource.manifest (local-exec):   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
null_resource.manifest (local-exec):                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
null_resource.manifest (local-exec):   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to  port 80: Connection refused
null_resource.manifest (local-exec): 100    32  100    32    0     0     64      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    64
null_resource.manifest (local-exec): {"message":"404 File Not Found"}
null_resource.manifest: Creation complete after 1s [id=5357322425754425058]
```

I'm not sure if the 404 is valid, or if the connection refused means I have the wrong endpoint/token/port?

I'm not sure why I'm getting the port 80 connection refused message. The URL is HTTPS and I am using `--location`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a lowercase `-o` to specify the local file name.
Your uppercase `-O` does not take an argument, and specifies that you want to use the remote filename when saving the output.

I presume that curl interprets  `'./.terraform/REDACTED/src/manifest.yml'` as the first url to fetch rather than as a file name.

If you run your curl command with the `-v` flag, you may see for yourself.